# How to launch local system application from Remote Desktop Application (Windows 2008R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server

I'm new to using Remote Desktop Services on Windows server 2008 R2.

I'm trying to find out whether it's possible to fire up a local application [based on file extension?] on the local client when opened from another published application running on the terminal server.

You've been able to do this for some time in Citrix, but wandered whether anybody have any experience of this using just the Windows 2008 server?

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it's not possible natively with TS and RDP. Writing a virtual channel handler for doing so shouldn't be too complex, though. Do you know any programing ?

Comment: thanks for response stephane, yes i do, mostly in .net 3.5/4.  Do you know of any samples of how you'd implement this?

Comment: I've written a couple of RDV virtual channel applications (and a class framework for that) but in Delphi only. However: google pointed me to this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/TSAddinInCS.aspx and the documentation is there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383552%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Working with the API isn't too complex, though. The main problem I encountered was that I didn't understand, at first, that the thigh worked like UDP and I had to handle lost packets and out-of-order packets (and rewrite my code to handle it). Since then, dynamic virtual channel pretty much have solved the problem.